# hibernate @OneToMany DTO @Where invalid

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to find out the result according to the condition competition, but what is effective is the annotation above the ExtendModule.getExtendFieldList. I want the annotations above to take effect using ExtendModuleUndeletedData.getExtendFieldlist.

I analyze the reason, hibernate proxy ExtendModuleUndeletedData, when I call ExtendModuleUndeletedData.getExtendFieldList, hibernate proxy invoke ExtendModule.getExtendFieldList.

I don't want hibernate proxy invoke annotation ExtendModule.getExtendFieldList. I really want to call the annotation of ExtendModuleUndeletedData.getExtendFieldList.

repository

```
public interface ExtendModuleRepository extends BaseRepository<ExtendModule> {
    List<ExtendModuleUndeletedData> findByDelIsFalse(String tableName, Sort sort);
}
```

entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_extend_module")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ExtendModule extends CreateBaseEntity {
    private String tableName;
    private String label;
    private int sort;
    private List<ExtendField> extendFieldList;
    private boolean del = false; 


    @OrderBy("sort asc")
    @Where(clause = "del=true")// <---- valid annotation
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "extendModuleId", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<ExtendField> getExtendFieldList() {
        return extendFieldList;
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint", length=1)
    public boolean isDel() {
        return del;
    }

}
```

dto entity

```
public interface ExtendModuleUndeletedData {

    @OrderBy("sort asc")
    @Where(clause = "del=false")// <---- invalid annotation
    List<ExtendField> getExtendFieldList();

    boolean isDel();

    String getId();

    String getLabel();

    int getSort();
}
```

ExtendModuleUndeletedData = DTO

ExtendModule = table entity

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I want the annotation @Where in dto （ExtendModuleUndeletedData ） to take effect